# Whats the difference between : kafka, filebeats and logstash?

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, filebeat

I worked a little bit with those 3 technologies on some small projects, but I have a feeling that they  *kindah* do the same job, three of them take data from one place and send it over to another one (they do data ingestion), am I wrong ? and when should I choose kafka or filebeats to send data considering the throughputs ?

Answer (score 3):

They are different tools that in some use cases have functions that could overlap.

**Kafka** is an distributed streaming platform that store data, can do pub/sub and can be used as a message queue like RabbitMQ for example.

**Filebeat** is a log shipper that read log files, or any other text files, and can ship those logs to some destinations, it supports sending data to elasticsearch, logstash or kafka.

**Logstash** is an ETL tool, it has input plugins to receive data from different sources, filter plugins to process the data and output plugins to send it elsewhere.

For example, when you are using the Elastic Stack for log analysis, it is pretty common to combine the three.

You can have multiple filebeats reading logs on remote machines and sending those logs to a Kafka Cluster, you will then have one or more logstash instances consuming those logs from Kafka, processing and sending the data to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 2):

- [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) is an event streaming platform. It stores data, it does pub/sub, it processes data.
- Logstash and [File]beats are part of the Elastic ecosystem and are commonly used for streaming data into Elasticsearch. They can also stream data to and from other sources.

The only overlap that I see is Apache Kafka includes Kafka Connect which can also be used for streaming data from Kafka to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Logstash and beats can be used for more than elasticsearch output

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so what I understand is 3 of them do streaming data to an end-point, which means they are similar ? if so what's the difference ?